# Keep row if the value on column contain certains regex elements

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Hello I have a df such as

```
COL1 COL2
Seq1 SeqB.2_1
Seq2 SeqA.1
Seq2 SeqZ_3
Seq3 Bon_0
Seq2 Buui.1
```

and I would like to only keep row were there is a `_Number` at the end of the `COL2` value

Here I should get:

```
COL1 COL2
Seq1 SeqB.2_1
Seq2 SeqZ_3
Seq3 Bon_0
```

Does someone have na idea ?

I tried :

```
df[df['COL2'].str.contains("_/\[[0-9]+\]/")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it: `_\d$`

See example: https://regex101.com/r/BP3Jnj/1